# How to take z scores of averages

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

I have a bunch of neuropsychological test scores for patients and controls which I have then grouped into cognitive domains and averaged the scores across each individual test to get domain averages for each participant. I want to use z scores of single patient vs control group to look for significance in each domain. My problem is the z score uses standard deviation and I don'd know how to calculate this for the domains in the control group. Do I sum all the standard deviations of the individual tests or do I calculate from the domain averages (so it would be the deviation of the mean of the means)?

Comment: One generally uses t-tests for this.

Comment: Thanks Carl, but we are using the Z-scores to standardise the unequally weighted tasks

Comment: One can use z-statistics when the standard deviations are known, when they are estimated from the population, one corrects for the error by using t-statistics. BTW, only in medicine would anyone say "Z-scores". The "z" is not usually capitalized, and it is not a score.

Comment: So essentially I am trying to compare one participant to twelve controls. I understand now why t-statistics are better but it doesn't wipe out the fact that I have tasks with unequal weightings. For example in the 'executive' domain I have one task that has a total possible score of 60 and one test with a total of 6. If I averaged across those the one out of 6 would have very little bearing on the overall mean even if they are significantly impaired. Do you have any suggestions as to which tests I can use?

Comment: So far, I know that your data is not paired. That rules out the more powerful tests. It is unclear from your description what should be used. 1) Is the data normally distributed? 2) How many patients are in the test group? If I take you at your word that there is only one test subject, then one-sample Wilcoxon might be useful. Wilcoxon is the non-parametric version of a t-test. A t-test would be parametric but requires normal conditions. I would not use one-sample t-testing without reasonable evidence of normality.

Comment: Thank you Carl, that's really helpful. The data is unfortunately not normal. There are 13 patients in the test group and 12 controls but we wanted to look at it as a case series and so treating each patient as a single case. I shall look at the Wilcoxon.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the [One-Sample Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test](http://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/NonParaTest-SignRank1). However, I think you need to do a two-sample test to compare difference of location, e.g., [Mann-Whitney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test), as well as a [Conover test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_ranks_test) which is a non-parametric test for difference of variance. I like the Wikipedia entry on that last one (I wrote it, so I am partial, even though it is sloppy.)